# Stereo matching with images captured by different cameras(different FOV, viewpoint) not aligned

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision, stereoscopy

I'm trying to get depth of some object in the scene and I don't want to use any other sensors except for cameras(I can use two cameras).

So, I think it should be a problem of 'Stereo matching' and I'm planning to extract disparity map from stereo images to get depth information.

But the problem is, I have constraints such as :

1. Two cameras are not aligned. All of (x, y, z) positions are different.
2. Two cameras' FOV(Field Of View)s are different. One is wider than the other.
3. Two cameras' viewpoints are different.
4. Two cameras have different resolution.

In this case, is it possible to do stereo matching correctly?
If so, how can it be possible?

I know that for stereo matching, epipolar geometry and fundamental matrix is very important.
But as far as I know, fundamental matrix always belongs to one camera.
Might relation between two fundamental matrices from two cameras be the solution to this problem?

Thank you.

--------------------------------- EDIT -------------------------------------

[Stereo image under different camera, resolution, viewpoint, FOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3e6b.jpg)

[Rectified image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igwf0.jpg)

Through Stereo Camera Calibrator of MATLAB, I got stereoParams and I did rectification using it.

But the rectified image is too distorted to get disparity map.

I wonder I am going right, or not.

Is there any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: If you know the distance between the cameras it should be possible.   Look up essential matrix and read http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post and added stereo image and rectified image. Can you give me feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Since your stereo setting, your cameras and field of views are different , I think you first need to do camera calibration, after calibration you do rectification on your images as below.
 [Epipolar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWn5v.jpg)

After these, you'll have regular stereo setting, with known camera geometry. Then you can extract disparities. 
There is nice tutorial here : [ROS Steroe Calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration)

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post and added stereo image and rectified image. Can you give me feedback?

Comment: It seems your done something wrong in rectification. I edit my post and add two rectified images, to give you a hint.